# How can I make the twitter-like hover 'Follow' button with bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Now I have the button with which, I can follow user, or un-follow.
Now when the target user is already followed. it's shown just like this.

[image: Un-Follow]

Then the target user is not followed, it's shown just like this.

[image: Follow]

I'd like it to be shown 'following' when the target user is already followed.
Then when I bring mouse cursor over the button, the display should be changed to 'Un-Follow'.

How can I do that with bootstrap?

**view**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% unless user == current_user %>
      <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
        <%= link_to(unfollow_user_path(user), :remote => true, :class => 'btn') do %>
       <i class="icon-remove"></i>
       Un-Follow
     <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to(follow_user_path(user) ,:remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-primary') do %>
        <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
        Follow
        <%end%>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
        <%= link_to(new_user_session_path , :class => 'btn btn-primary') do %>
        <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
        Follow
        <%end%>
<% end %>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="/user/1/follow" class="btn btn-primary" data-remote="true">
    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
    Follow
</a>

<a href="/user/1/unfollow" class="btn btn-primary" data-remote="true">
    <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
    Un-Follow
</a>
```

UPDATE:

```
<a href="/user/1/unfollow" class="btn" data-remote="true" onhover="someFunction()">
    <i id="Following" class="icon-remove"></i>
    Following
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the onHover event You can use jQuery to change the "class" attribute of the button you want to change the text too.

i.e.

```
<a href="/user/1/follow"  onHover="someFunction();" class="btn btn-primary" data-remote="true">
    <i id="Following" class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
    Following
</a>


someFunction() {
  $('i#Following').attr("class", "icon-ok icon-white").innerText("Unfollow");
}
```

you get the picture hopefully.

Edit:
This is the full code that should fire the code in someFunction on mouse over.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function someFunction()
{
 alert("Hello");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="/user/1/unfollow" class="btn" data-remote="true" onmouseover="someFunction();return true;" >
    <i  id="Following" class="icon-remove"></i>
    Following
</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is extra/missing quotes in your Javascript

Comment: This is not exactly production ready code. The OP will have to write the 100% rite code, but the work is 90% already done.

Comment: ummm, I tried this but it won't work on mine:(  <%= link_to(unfollow_user_path(user), :onHover => "someFunction()", :remote => true, :class => 'btn') do %>

Comment: What's the HTML that gets generated from that?

Comment: @user373466 I updated my Question. Please check the bottom part.

Comment: Anyone can help with this please??

Comment: @user373466 Thanks!! Alert worked perfect! the previous JS code you provided, it seems not working

Comment: Hi cat like I said, the jQuery code is not 100% correct, but the API function you need to use are attr() and innerText() find out what they do and use the right syntax.

Comment: @user373466 Can't you help me anymore than this?

Comment: You need to be more descriptive than, "it's not working". Please provide the code otherwise there's not much I can do.

Comment: @user373466 sorry about that. I wanted to mean that nothing happens even when I bring mouse cursor over the button. I'm checking web console with FireFox. It also won't show me any JS function firing.  With alert function, it was working fine. I really wonder why previous function even won't be fired.